# Remove range of words with sed

Tags: sed

I'm trying to remove a range of words in Unix command line with sed from a file and I just can't figure it out. For example, how can I remove the words at positions 2-4?
If the file contains: "This is a file created by me." I want it to be: "This created by me."
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please post a clear sample of input/output . i.e.: "i have this" and  "I need this"

Comment: Is it a requirement that you use `sed`? The `cut` command would work much better here.

Comment: `cut` as above, or `awk` would be a better solution to this sort of problem. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I know with cut or awk it's easier but I need to do it with sed ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with GNU sed (to print word 1 and word 5 to last word):

```
echo "This is a file created by me." | sed 'y/ /\n/' | sed -n '1p;5,$p' | sed 'N;N;N;y/\n/ /'
```

Output:

```
This created by me.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried with sed s/[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]//'2,4' file but it doesn't work, I suppose the range it's not good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also use `awk` for this:

```
echo "This is a file created by me." | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (i<2||i>4) printf "%s ",$i;print ""}'
This created by me.
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(\s+\S+){3}//' file
```